# How do I get my Div to show up?

Tags: css, html

Here is the link to my code 
http://jsfiddle.net/8B875/

Why exactly is my my Textboxsquare not showing up?

The HTML

```
<div id="textbox"></div>
<div id="textboxSquare"></div>
```

The CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

#textbox {
    border: 1px solid #848484;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 30px;
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    outline:0;
    height:25px;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 300px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
}

#textboxSquare {
    display:inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:25px; 
    width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is there, you just can't see its border. Add

```
border: 1px solid #848484;
```

and you will see it.

Comment: I am an idiot I understand now that a border needs to be added now, thanks

Comment: Can you please mark this answer as correct by clicking the green checkbox?

Comment: Gah, I am fed up with this. Is there a way to ignore questions by `user*` users?

Answer (score 0):

It is showing up, you just can't see it.

If you add `border:1px solid pink;` to the CSS you will see it.

Your first box has height and width, the second box doesn't have enough properties to be rendered visible. Add heigh, border properties etc.